# Rails ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From time to time, my rails application sends me bug reports for ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken on random `create` or `update` actions. I have the `csrf_meta_tags` in my head tag and 99% of my requests work.

In the documentation, I have seen than I can try a `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` but this option is suppose to be for APIs only.

I'm not sure what to do. Do you have any advices ?

I'm using Rails 4.1 but I have the same problem with older versions.

Comment: Is this in production? They could be legitimate cross-site forgery attacks. Log all the things, even happy actions, and see if they pop up in the expected flow of the app.

Comment: Yes it's in production but I know for sure, at least some of it are not cross-site forgery attacks!

Answer (score 0):

This must the case when you perform `custom` Ajax. You have to pass `csrf` token explicitly. Something like this works for me almost 90%.

```
$.ajax your_url ,
   beforeSend: (xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader "X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content")
```

Yes, it is not advisable to use

```
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

unless you have some mechanism to distinguish between good and fraudulent request. In api, we usually have some `token` which helps to verify the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing session_id in a cookie, those requests may be from users with disabled cookies. In fact, they will not be able even to sign in, because the CSRF token is stored in the session.